# 'str' object has no attribute 'disconnect'

Tags: python, django, twython

What`s wrong with the method?
'stream' is the method name I declared for it to start the streamer and it works. However when I wrote this method to disconnect the streamer, it have error saying that 'str' object has no attribute 'disconnect'. Can anyone give me example or tell me what did I missed out?

```
def twitter_stop(request):
    stream = request.session['stream']

    stream.disconnect()
     return HttpResponse(request)
```

updated:
This is my start method which is working:

```
def twitter_start(request):
     stream = MyStreamer(settings.CONSUMER_KEY, settings.CONSUMER_SECRET,
                settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
     # get the stream object from the SESSION
      request.session['stream'] = stream
     # get the keywords from the models
        keywords = Keys.objects.all()
        stream.statuses.filter(track=keywords)
         return HttpResponse(request)
```

Comment: You're going to need to give more context, and how you're setting up `request.session['stream']`. Because it looks `stream` is a string and not what you think it is.

Comment: @Shurane What do u mean by more context? Anyw, I have updated the start method of using the stream.. can guide me along?

Comment: Looks like a de-serialization issue. Do you need to store it in the session? If so, you could try to serialize and de-serialize it manually.

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your code example. That is not syntactically valid Python without proper indentation.

Comment: Possible causes I can think of: 1. some other code overwrites `session['stream']` 2. you have a serialization and/or deserialization issue. Assuming you have settings.DEBUG set, you should be able to inspect what `stream` looks like in the `twitter_stop()` view...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 2 **request** objects are different ; the stream you assign in **twitter_start**
in **request.session** is lost after the execution of the function. Use a global variable
to store the stream, eg:

```
global STREAM

def twitter_start(request):
    global STREAM
    STREAM = MyStreamer(settings.CONSUMER_KEY, settings.CONSUMER_SECRET,
                        settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

    # get the keywords from the models
    keywords = Keys.objects.all()
    STREAM.statuses.filter(track=keywords)
    return HttpResponse(request)

def twitter_stop(request):
    STREAM.disconnect()
    return HttpResponse(request)
```

Comment: The 2 request objects are indeed different, but you should read about what the `request.session` is for - yes, storing stuff from one request to the other. Using a global is definitly the wrong solution in a possibly multithreaded and/or multiprocess execution context, for very obvious reasons. To make a long story short: this is about the worst possible answer :-/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: you're completly right! Sorry I replied a bit too fast I think...